# How to create an Add to Cart button to add multiple products?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a website based on magento c.e 1.7, now i need a "add to cart" button on my cms page which add multiple simple products to the cart.
Right now i have id of those products, there is no problem with quantity as i only need to add each product with quantity one.

Thanks in advance,
Sarvagya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution it is:

I just used the array of product ids and applied it to the loop which takes every product and add it to the cart.

Code :

```
foreach($prod_array as $product_id){ /*$prod_array contains the ids of products */
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')// set the current store ID
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                     // load the product object
                     ->load($product_id);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
        $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
        $cart->addProduct($product,1); /* In my case the quantity is 1 */
    }
$cart->save();
    $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

may be it will help someone

Answer (score 4):

You can add a product via `POST` to `checkout/cart/add/product/<id>` and add more simple items via `$_GET['related_products']  = array('id', 'id2', ...)`